# Exclude class in target if Macro is set to 1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macros, ios8

I defined a preprocessor macro like:

```
#define ENABLE_SPECIAL_FEATURES 1
```

So now I am able to include or exclude Code snippets from beeing in the target or not. But I want to have a possibility to do the same with a complete class. So if the macro is set to "1", the class should be included or not.

Is that possible?

UPDATE:

Is the same mechanism possible with frameworks?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply wrap the entire class declaration (`.h` file) and definition (`.m`) within that macro value

YourClass.h:

```
#if ENABLE_SPECIAL_FEATURES

#import <Whatever.h>
@interface YourClass : NSObject
....
@end

#endif // ENABLE_SPECIAL_FEATURES
```

YourClass.m:

```
#if ENABLE_SPECIAL_FEATURES

#import "YourClass.h"
@implementation YourClass
....
@end

#endif // ENABLE_SPECIAL_FEATURES
```

This way you won't even see the class despite the header and implementation file being compiled into the project.

Comment: @davidOhara I don't understand your question.